# css vendor specific calc

Tags: css, less, css-calc

I came accross the following css code.  It is using vendor prefixes for the css calc function.  As far as I remember vendor prefixes were for the left side of the style definition, basically they are vendor specific properties for new functionality in the browser but not yet standardized.  I think I am correct to say that the following is not correct.

```
#test {
    width: ~"calc(100% - 360px)";
    width: ~"-webkit-calc(100% - 360px)";
    width: ~"-moz-calc(100% - 360px)";
}
```

as -webkit-calc is on the right.

Comment: "As far as I remember vendor prefixes were for the left side of the style definition" - No, vendor prefixes may appear basically *anywhere* (e.g. [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::-moz-placeholder), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/gradient) etc.). For your particular example though,  `-webkit-calc` and `-moz-calc` do not make much sense since *today* you barely find any WebKit or FF browser that does not support standard `calc`. But they *are* valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`calc` is a CSS *function* not a property (which `width` is) and so as it is/was experimental, it requires/d prefixing.

So it's all out of date anyway but `-prefix-calc` WOULD have been correct at the time.

[**Current Support**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) *indicates* that it can probably be used unprefixed.

[**Calc @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Comment: http://robertnyman.com/css3/calc/calc.html unprefixed will take precedence over prefixed, but this is what they look like with their prefixes

Comment: I see them here http://jonkemp.com/css/cross-browser-css-calc.html and https://gist.github.com/jonkemp/2280688 the problem is my bundler is throwing them as errors and I get a big blob or errors in my minified css.